# Google Maps Api shows grey map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to integrate Google Maps JavaScript API in my WordPress website.

I created an API key, and I added a pure html code block in my page.

Before it worked perfectly, but now it only show a grey piece. When I zoom out and drag the map around, the following picture is visible:

[image]

This is my code in the html block:

```
<div id="googlemaps"></div>
<script>
    var map;
    function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googlemaps'), {
            center: {lat: 51.341667, lng: 4.21444},
            zoom: 8
         });
    }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR-API-KEY&callback=initMap"
async defer></script>
```

And YES, I replaced YOUR-API-KEY with my API key in my code (this is just so others won't use the generated code).

I don't know what is wrong with the map. I do not have errors in my web console.

Comment: How are you setting the size of the `<div>` with id "googlemaps"?

Comment: @geocodezip yes, I do, #googlemaps {height: 460px;}

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], I can't reproduce your issue with the posted code (which means it is something WordPress is doing to your code...)

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script>
    var map;
    function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googlemaps'), {
            center: {lat: 51.341667, lng: 4.21444},
            zoom: 8,
             backgroundColor: '#fffff', 
         });
    }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR-API-KEY&callback=initMap"
async defer></script
```

```html
<div id="googlemaps"></div>
```

Use  backgroundColor property

Comment: That is no solution at all. There is something wrong with the map, giving it a white background does NOT solve the problem!

Comment: There is an map option to change a background color: backgroundColor  and other options 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions

Answer (score 0):

Call google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize') inside initMap() as you have resized the map div.

```
 var map;
function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googlemaps'), {
        center: {lat: 51.341667, lng: 4.21444},
        zoom: 8
     });
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')
}
```