# Google Maps JavaScript API shows grey blank box instead of map

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, ionic4

I can't seem to get a map to show on an Ionic Application, with Google Maps JavaScript API.

So far I have tried `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')`, since I have changed the width of the map div... Saw that from a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41597617/8664756). FYI the map used to work fine, but had a few glitches when I tried to pan around.

In map.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { google } from 'google-maps';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.scss'],
})
export class MapComponent implements OnInit {
  // Map setup
  @ViewChild('mapElement', {static: true}) mapElement: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;
  map: google.maps.Map;

  constructor() {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('Map')
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, {
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    });
    google.maps.event.trigger(this.map, 'resize')
    console.log('Map Seconded')
  }
}
```

The HTML in `map.component.ts`

```html
<div id="map-element" #mapElement></div>
```

The CSS is used to style the map-element in `global.css`

```css
#map-element {
    display: block;
    height: 400px;
}
```

Just so you can compare API Keys here is mine I have a feeling that is where the problem might be, after I have found a solution I'll have it regenerated, `AIzaSyB6RgF7vmUE0mjk_glikiuuSmpGpaNiA24`

When I view the app on Google Chrome and try to zoom in and out of the map I get this error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'zoom' of null`

Comment: Is the map location static or does it change? If it is static, why not use a google map iframe embed code? It's what I've been using in my app and its super simple and seems to work great.

Comment: No, It's not a static map, I will be using directions services also.

Comment: Gotcha! Good luck with your problem :-)

Answer (score 1):

Personally I needed a location from google maps on my website, so what I did is that I embedded the the location from google maps, and you do so by clicking on "Share" and then "Embed a map" and then you copy the html code and put it in your html code.

```
<a><iframe src="html code" class="map" width="250" height="200" frameborder="0" 
style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe></a>
```

Comment: Yeah, that one I do know about, the thing is I want to use the core features of Google Maps to add stuff like custom markers for an Uber-like app. Since using the map as an `iframe` I don't have a way of controlling stuff like that.